# Enter key not working on froala editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, html-editor, froala

i am using froala js 1.9 js .. It was working well till yest ..but now enter key is not working on the editor.

```
$('#txt_blog_editor').editable({
            inlineMode: false,
            minHeight: 700,
            //height: 700,
            plainPaste: false,
            width: 1097,
            allowedImageTypes: ["jpeg", "jpg", "png"],
            borderColor: '#00008b',
            inverseSkin: false,
            spellcheck: true,
            imageUploadURL: 'BlogPhotos.ashx',
            autosaveInterval: 1000,
            imageErrorCallback: function (data) {
                if (data.errorCode == 1) {

                }

                // No link in upload response.
                else if (data.errorCode == 2) {

                }

                // Error during file upload.
                else if (data.errorCode == 3) {

                }

                // Parsing response failed.
                else if (data.errorCode == 4) {

                }
            },
            buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'sep', 'align', 'insertOrderedList', 'insertUnorderedList', 'outdent', 'indent', 'sep', 'createLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'undo', 'redo', 'insertHorizontalRule','color']
        });
```

This is my code to intialize...

i have checked enter key is working on any other page elemnts but not this editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a new version 1.2.0. You should try updating to it and maybe that would fix your problem.